# Using OR in and IF statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Can I use OR in an IF statement? Something like this:

```
if %str% equ 1 **OR** %str% equ 2 echo %str%
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. You can do this with a `goto`:

```
if %str% equ 1 goto dosomething
if %str% equ 2 goto dosomething
goto aftersomething

:dosomething
  rem do something

:aftersomething
```

Or with a temporary variable:

```
set var=
if %str% equ 1 set var=1
if %str% equ 2 set var=1

if defined var (
  rem do something
)
```